# When do I need to use the new operator when declaring nodes in C++?

Tags: c++

When creating a node in c++, when do I need to use the `new` operator to ensure that memory is available to allocate.

For instance, this function does not use `new` when declaring the node pointer NewNode used to find the end of an existing linked list for purposes of adding a node to the end of the list, however it does use `new` when actually adding the node to the end of the list. Is this because the node pointer is being used as a non-dynamic memory allocation that points to other memory that has already been allocated dynamically or for some other reason? Would it be incorrect syntax or logic wise to use the new (nothrow) in front of the NewNode declaration?

```
typedef Node* NodePtr; /*a type definition for NodePtr for ease of use in `the larger program this function is a part of*/`

void AddNode(char NewChar, NodePtr List)
{
    NodePtr NewNode = List;  //make NewNode point to List

    while (NewNode->Link != NULL)     //find end of linked list
        NewNode = NewNode->Link;

    NewNode->Link = new (nothrow) Node;  //create a new Node at the end of the list

    if (NewNode->Link == NULL)  //make sure Node was created
        return;

    NewNode = NewNode->Link;  //make NewNode point to the Node just created
    NewNode->Ch = NewChar;    //fill Ch part of NewNode
    NewNode->Link = NULL;     //make sure the list ends with NULL
}
void TestAddNode(NodePtr List)
{
    char NewChar;

    cout << "\n\n----------------   Testing AddNode   -------------------\n\n";

    cout << "Character to be added? ";
    NewChar = cin.get();
    cin.ignore();

    if (NewChar == '\n')  // User pressed just enter key.
    {
        cout << "Aborting AddNode...";
        return;
    }

    cout << NewChar;
    cout << " --  Adding \'" << NewChar << "\'";

    AddNode(NewChar, List);

    cout << "\n\nThe new list: ";
    ShowList(List); //show list is another function that outputs the list
}
```

Comment: It's generally not a good idea type `typedef` a raw pointer type. It is more succinctly and precisely denoted by the `*` notation or a `Ptr_` template. With the `typedef` one has to look for a definition of the name.

Comment: `NewNode` is misleadingly named. It's neither a new node nor a pointer to a new node. A better name would be just `p`, which doesn't indicate more than that this is a pointer.

Comment: a better name would be ListIter

Comment: So, because NewNode is not actually creating a new node, it's just a node pointer, it does not need to use the new (nothrow) because it's just declaring a pointer in a way similar to how you would declare an int, char, etc. Meaning that the memory will be reserved for this pointer as soon as the program starts and it will continue to be reserved until the program ends?

Comment: It's a local automatic variable, just like an `int` variable, yes. Memory is reserved for it somewhere before the execution reaches the declaration. Typically this is on entry to the function body, where typically memory is reserved for all the automatic local variables.

Comment: The checking of whether allocation fails, and then just `return`, means that *if* allocation fails then the function will silently not have done its job, and there's nothing to indicate whether it did or not. By returning a `bool` the function can indicate to the calling code whether it succeeded. Alternatively (and better) by just using ordinary `new`, no `nothrow`, in which case an exception is thrown if the allocation fails.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Cheers and hth. - Alf, I think I understand the difference now.

Comment: So without the nothrow, it will automatically indicate an error or would I need to write something to indicate an error to the user?

Comment: I edited the post to show the function that tests the first function we have been discussing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `new` only when dynamically-allocating new memory for storing a new node. In your case, `NewNode` is just pointing to the existing memory pointed to by `List`, so this is not the right place for using the `new` operator.